# How to set tab position in PHP with PHPWord

Tags: phpword

I want to set tab position any line
http://www.phpdocx.com/img/sampleScripts/WordContent/example_addText_4.png

Comment: Add your relevant code and be more specific on your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example in the phpword samples for just that, see [php word samples - tabs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_02_TabStops.php)

The same example code content copied here for your convenience:

```
// Ads styles
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle(
    'multipleTab',
    array(
        'tabs' => array(
            new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('left', 1550),
            new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('center', 3200),
            new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('right', 5300),
        )
    )
);

$phpWord->addParagraphStyle(
    'rightTab',
    array('tabs' => array(new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('right', 9090)))
);

$phpWord->addParagraphStyle(
    'centerTab',
    array('tabs' => array(new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('center', 4680)))
);

// New portrait section
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Add listitem elements
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars("Multiple Tabs:\tOne\tTwo\tThree"), null, 'multipleTab');
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars("Left Aligned\tRight Aligned"), null, 'rightTab');
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars("\tCenter Aligned"), null, 'centerTab');
```

Comment: Note: strings containing `\t` must be surrounded in double quotes!